# Small question regarding open mappings

Tags: general-topology, functions

A function $f:X\to Y$
  between topological spaces is said to be open if for every $U\subseteq X$
  which is open $f\left(U\right)\subseteq Y$
  is open.

I'm trying to show that a function is open iff for all $x\in X$
 , $f\left(x\right)$
  is an interior point of $f\left(X\right)$
 . To show that the second condition implies openness it suffices to show that given an open set $U\subseteq X$ implies that for all $x\in U$
  there is an open subset $V\subseteq Y$
  such that $f\left(x\right)\in V\subseteq f\left(U\right)$ but I can't seem to manage to show that.

The claim is actually incorrect but someone might find the comments to be useful.

Comment: It’s not true: if $f$ is a surjection, every point of $f[X]$ is an interior point of $f[X]=Y$ no matter **what** $f$ is.

Comment: Is it possible to formulate some other criteria for openness of $f$ in terms of how to acts on individual points?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a trivial reformulation of the definition: $f$ is open iff for each open $U\subseteq X$ and $x\in U$, $f(x)$ is in the interior of $f[U]$. I suppose that you could say that $f$ is *open at* $x$ if $f(x)$ is in the interior of $f[U]$ for each open nbhd $U$ of $x$ and then say that $f$ is open iff it is open at each point of $f$, but I’m not sure that *open at a point* is an interesting concept.

Comment: This is a bit strange. In a course I took recently we proved the following theorem "if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  is an open set and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$
  is a continuously differentiable function such that $\mbox{rank}D_{f}\left(x\right)=m$
  for all $x\in A$
  then $f$
  is an open function". To do this we were told that it sufficed to show that for all $x\in A$
 , $f\left(x\right)$
  is an interior point of $f\left(A\right)$. 
But it doesn't seem to suffice according to this conversation.

Comment: You have a lot of extra structure there. Let’s see; showing that each $f(x)$ (for $x\in A$) is in the $\Bbb R^m$-interior of $f[A]$ would show that $f[A]$ is open in $\Bbb R^m$. The same proof would apply to any open subset of $A$ to show that its image is open in $\Bbb R^m$, so yes, you would in this case be able to conclude that $f$ is open.

Comment: The general analogue would be something like this: You have an open $A\subseteq X$ and a function $f:A\to Y$ with certain properties. If from these properties you can show that $f(x)\in\operatorname{int}_Yf[A]$ for all $x\in A$, and if the restriction of $f$ to any open subset of $A$ still has these properties, then you can conclude that $f$ is open.

Comment: Great, you've helped me a lot Brian, I appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure!${}$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Does the notation $f[X]$ mean or imply anything else than $f(X)$? Just curious, since I've never used it, and I've rarely seen it.

Comment: @julien: I make a notational distinction (that others also make) between $f(X)$, the image of the single element $X$ of the domain of $f$, and $f[X]=\{f(x):x\in X\}$. Thus, if $f:\wp(A)\to Y$, and $X\subseteq A$, I will of course write $f(X)$ for the element of $Y$ that is the image of $X$ under $f$. But if $f:A\to Y$, and $X\subseteq A$, I think it sloppy to write $f(X)$ for $\{f(x):x\in X\}$ and prefer to write $f[X]$. Another notation for this is $f^{\to}X$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, thanks, I didn't say you were alone to do that. But there are not so many of you either, from my personal experience. It is indeed sloppy to write $f(X)$. But I'm afraid the harm is done (hum, this does not sound like proper english...).